# Multiple IFs in 1 formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, ifs

I'm trying to extract sections of text from an Excel cell then put some of those parts together.
Using LEFT, MID, TRIM, SUBSTITUTE & REPT (mainly helped by contributions on this site), I've managed to split each section down (they are separated by dashes) into it's constituent parts.
I've managed to do the easy bit which is to add sections 2 and 3 together (separated by dashes) using =L2&"-"&M2&"-"&.
I want to add the last section but the problem I have is that some of the names have 5 sections, some 6 and some 7 so I need a formula that says something like "If cells 9 & 10 are empty, use cell 8, if cell 10 is empty use 9 and if neither 9 or 10 are empty, use 10".
I've had a go with IF and AND but keep getting error messages, mainly about too many arguments. Any help would be much appreciated, I still quite a newbie to formula writing.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting problem to work on but it's near impossible to help you without a good reproducable example. Please refer to [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  Do you have access to the `CONCAT` and `TEXTJOIN` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming sections 8,9 and 10 are in columns R:T, you could use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(R2:T2<>""),R2:T2)
```

Comment: I'm one of those self-confessed Geeks who, when asked by someone who thinks I know a lot about a lot "Do you know everything?" I answer "No...not yet." I wish I had time to learn all of things I'd like to - MS Access, Excel formulas (or should that be formulae), Dynamo, LISP, the piano...Many thanks, here I am, working from home, blundering through complicated IFs & ANDs and all the time, someone like you can shame me with a single line. Many thanks.

Comment: I've just Googled LOOKUP to educate myself and found there is also XLOOKUP as I'm using 365. So there's tomorrow sorted.